# ORACLE min date row for each code

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

**PREVI_INFO**

```
╔══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╗
║ previ_id ║ code_station ║ code_modele ║    date_previ    ║ type_previ ║
╠══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╣
║   501201 ║         2952 ║          48 ║ 29/01/2017 15:00 ║ AUTO       ║
║   501156 ║         2952 ║          48 ║ 30/01/2017 07:00 ║ AUTO       ║
╚══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

**PREVI_VAL**

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ previ_id ║ code_scenario ║        temps        ║ valeur_debit ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════╣
║   501201 ║            -1 ║ 30/01/2017 10:00:00 ║ 2,024        ║
║   501201 ║            -1 ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,215        ║
║   501201 ║             0 ║ 30/01/2017 10:00:00 ║ 1,456        ║
║   501201 ║             0 ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 1.687        ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

**QUERY**

For a given **code_model** I need to get the nearest **previ_val** for a list of **code_scenario**

What I have now :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT previ_id, type_previ
  FROM (
    SELECT previ_id, type_previ
    FROM PREVI.previ_info
    WHERE code_modele = '48'
    ORDER BY date_previ DESC
  ) pi
  WHERE ROWNUM < 2
) pi
JOIN PREVI.previ_val pv
ON pv.previ_id = pi.previ_id
```

which gives me

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ previ_id ║ type_previ ║ code_scenario ║        temps        ║    valeur_debit    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 10:00:00 ║ 2,027503327181698  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,289291759560228  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 16:00:00 ║ 2,488605471829943  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 19:00:00 ║ 2,5768532759013274 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 22:00:00 ║ 2,5567552515698297 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 31/01/2017 01:00:00 ║ 2,4847510721331894 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 31/01/2017 04:00:00 ║ 2,371160558216584  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 10:00:00 ║ 2,027503327181698  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,281620351009415  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 16:00:00 ║ 2,4679642018714993 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 19:00:00 ║ 2,5426531265028185 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 22:00:00 ║ 2,510706411016839  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 31/01/2017 01:00:00 ║ 2,4287719529773804 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 31/01/2017 04:00:00 ║ 2,308307979316664  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 30/01/2017 10:00:00 ║ 2,027503327181698  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,2950103323648503 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 30/01/2017 16:00:00 ║ 2,506610245355028  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 30/01/2017 19:00:00 ║ 2,6144186413564663 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 30/01/2017 22:00:00 ║ 2,63992592676027   ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 31/01/2017 01:00:00 ║ 2,6660032204209982 ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0,25          ║ 31/01/2017 04:00:00 ║ 2,689414559791597  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

**Desired result**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ previ_id ║ type_previ ║ code_scenario ║        temps        ║    valeur_debit    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ -1            ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,289291759560228  ║
║   501201 ║ AUTO       ║ 0             ║ 30/01/2017 13:00:00 ║ 2,281620351009415  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

This gives me the row with the next date. if it is 30/01/2017 12:45, I need the row with 30/01/2017 13:00:00 not 10:00:00.
The codes are from a list. For the moment it is 0 and -1 only.

How can I improve my query to make it works ?

Comment: sweet table formatting

Comment: Could you explain "nearest" ? closes by date? before? after ?

Comment: I tried to explain it after the desired result. I need to get the date that is the next compared to now. Is this understandable ?

Comment: now you mean sysdate ?

Comment: sysdate or i can put it in a where close and add it inside my java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a given code_model I need to get the nearest previ_val for a list of code_scenario

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function. It is unclear how you are partitioning the data but something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT i.*,
         v.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY i.previ_id, v.code_scenario
                             ORDER BY ABS( i.date_previ - v.temps ) ) AS rn
  FROM   ( SELECT *
           FROM   ( SELECT *
                    FROM   PREVI_INFO
                    WHERE  i.code_modele = 48
                    ORDER BY date_previ DESC )
           WHERE ROWNUM = 1
         ) i
         INNER JOIN PREVI_VAL v
         ON ( i.previ_id = v.previ_id )
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Update**:

> I need to get the date that is the next compared to now.

This will join the tables where the `temps` value is after the `SYSDATE` and then get the first chronologically:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT i.*,
         v.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY i.previ_id, v.code_scenario
                             ORDER BY v.temps ) AS rn
  FROM   ( SELECT *
           FROM   ( SELECT *
                    FROM   PREVI_INFO
                    WHERE  i.code_modele = 48
                    ORDER BY date_previ DESC )
           WHERE ROWNUM = 1
         ) i
         INNER JOIN PREVI_VAL v
         ON (   i.previ_id = v.previ_id 
            AND v.temps >= SYSDATE )
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This query is not working. For example, you are taking the `code_scenario` from table `previ_info` instead of `previ_val` + Where should I put my where condition with `code_modele = xx` ?

Comment: The second query seems to work well. Where can I add the code_scenario that I need ? `where code_scenario IN (0,-1)`

Comment: Either as a `WHERE` clause to the sub-query containing the join or to the `ON` clause.